# How to make a dependable dropdown

Tags: php, laravel

[image: A picture for better understanding of what i want to do]
when i select a leave type e.g annual leave, i want the leave days of annual leave (as selected) to automatically show in the box beside it.
This is what my controller looks like

```
if($request->isMethod('POST')){
            $all_leave = new allLeave;
            $all_leave->employee_id = $user;
            $all_leave->leave_type = $request->input('leaveType');
            $all_leave->date_from = $request->input('dateFrom');
                $leaveDays = leaveType::all()->where('leave_type','=',$all_leave->leave_type)->pluck('leave_days');
                $leaveDays = empty($leaveDays[0]) ? 0 :  $leaveDays[0];
            $newTime = date('d-m-Y', (strtotime($all_leave->date_from.' + '.$leaveDays.' days')));
            $newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($newTime));
            $all_leave->date_to = $newDate;
            $all_leave->description = $request->input('description');
            $all_leave->save();
        }
global $leaveDays;

        $leaveType = leaveType::pluck('leave_type','leave_type');
        $allLeave = allLeave::all()->where('employee_id','=',$user);
        return view('leave.application', ['leave_t' => $leaveType, 'all_l' => $allLeave, 'leave_D' => $leaveDays]);
```

$all_leave->leave_type is a dropdown that is gotten from the database, each of it has its value. So I want the value of each dropdown to display without leaving the page according to whatever leave type that is selected.

$leaveDays should change according to whatever is selected in the dropdown.

This is what i have in my blade file:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'LeavessController@index', 'method' => 'POST'))}}
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        {{ Form::label('leave type', 'LEAVE TYPE :',['class' => 'col-sm-3 col-form-label']) }}   
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            {{ Form::select('leaveType',['Select Leave Type'] + $leave_t->all(),'',['class' => 'form-control m-b']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        {{ Form::label('date from', 'DATE FROM :',['class' => 'col-sm-3 col-form-label']) }}   
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            {{ Form::date('dateFrom', '', ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' =>'DATE FROM']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        {{ Form::label('discription', 'DISCRIPTION :',['class' => 'col-sm-3 col-form-label']) }}   
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            {{ Form::textarea('description', '', ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' =>'DISCRIPTION', 'row' => '4', 'cols' => '30']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align:center;">
                        {{ Form::submit('APPLY', ['class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-primary m-t-n-xs']) }}
                    </div>
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">LEAVE DAYS</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group row">   
                    <div class="col-sm-4"><span style="font-size:80px;">{{$leave_D}}Days</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you also post your view template

Comment: @RigelKent Have posted what i have for my Blade file.

Comment: What exactly do you want to acheive?

Comment: @RigelKent i have dded the picture and more detailed information to the picture

Comment: @RigelKent i want it that whenever a leave Type is selected from the dropdown, it should automatically display the value "leave days" as stated for the leave the person has selected without having to leave the page.

Comment: You'll need to have an AJAX request whenever you change the `Leave Type` select input and update the Leave Days

Comment: @RigelKent Please how do i do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204196/discussion-between-rigel-kent-and-nicandias).

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
public function getLeaveDays($leaveType)
{
    $days = //query to get count leaveDays;

    return response()->json([
        'leaveDays' => $days
    ]);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/get-leave-days/{leaveType}', 'Controller@getLeaveDays');
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').on('change', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url('get-leave-days') }}/' + $(this).val(),
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(res) {
                    $('.leave-days').text(res.data.days)
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please is it not possible to merge this conrtroller with the one i have before?

Comment: public function getLeaveDays($leaveType){
        $days = leaveType::all()->where('leave_type','=','leave_days');
        return response()->json([
            'leaveDays' => $days
            ]);
    }

Comment: thats the new controller i added. am having issues fetching the leave days because i dont know how to tage the day with the leave thats selected

Comment: am thinking I should add it in the controller I used before so I will be able to use the $leaveDays

Comment: and what would i use to display the days in my blade